# Meaning of double vertical bars in context: "let $q$ be a prime divisor of $n$ with $q^s|| n$."

Tags: notation, binomial-theorem, primality-test

I've been doing some reading about the AKS primality test. I specifically have been reading [this](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~linowitz/papers/mastersthesis.pdf). On page 19, I don't understand the notation involving the double vertical bars:
Let $q$ be a prime divisor of $n$ with $q^s|| n$.

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: I've seen it used sometimes with the meaning that $q^s\mid n$ but $q^{s+1}\nmid n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that $s$ is the greatest natural number such that $q^s$ divides $n$. Therefore $q^s$ divides $n$ but $q^{s+1}$ doesn't divide $n$.